# Yii1 - sanitize GET parameter in the before action

Tags: yii

I am trying to find if it possible to use the **beforeAction** in the controller to access the injected parameter.

For example, every action in the controller accepts **type** parameter, which I need to sanitize:

```
public function actionGetCustomPaymentsChunk($type) {

        $type = TextUtil::sanitizeString($type);

        // Get filter data
        $filter = FilterHelper::getFilterData();
        // Initialize components
        $totalCostPayableComponent = new TotalCostPayableComponent($filter);
        // Get chunk data
        $data = $totalCostPayableComponent->getCustomPaymentChunk($type);

        // Return content to client side
        $this->renderPartial('/partials/_payable_cost_chunk', array(
            'data'        => $data,
            'route'       => 'totalCostPayable/getCustomPaymentsGrid',
            'type'        => $type,
            'paymentType' => 'Custom',
        ));
    }
}
```

Is this possible to do (I am trying to avoid repetition)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to, what did you try?

Assuming the `$type` is passed via GET, you can modify it in a `beforeAction` and the modified value will be applied to the target action with a request like

`http://myhost.com/route/test?type=something`

using the below, `$type = "foo"` in any action in this controller.

```
protected function beforeAction($action)
{
    if (isset($_GET['type'])) {
        $_GET['type'] = 'foo';
    }
    ...
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}

public function actionTest($type)
{
   # $type === 'foo'
   ...
}
```

Change the manipulation in beforeAction to satisfy whatever your requirements are.

Comment: This is working fine, a bit too risky for me. 
Thanks for the help :).